# How can I create an outline around an object?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I want to use a geometry node to place a fixed number of instances on the outline of an object based on the camera's viewpoint. How can I place a fixed number of points on the outline of an object that looks like this image based on the view? The image is an just example of manually placing vertices. I also tried the method using boolean, but I didn't get a satisfactory result. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

---

I was able to place the points on the outline using the normal and the camera, but I did not have control over the exact number and position.

[image]

Update 6/4

-I succeeded in creating an outline around the object and resampling it to add dots! However, the curve is a bit unstable, so the position of the vertex flickers. I'll try to find a way to make it more stable.

blend file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nutIUEuca_n9tiB0d8Tlq4dizP3qhIs9/view?usp=sharing

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you already created the outline, or is this about the points AND the outline?

Comment: I want to place the points along an outline. The images are just manually placed vertices for illustrative purposes. Using normals and cameras, I was able to place the points on the outline, but I had no control over the exact location and number of points. I am trying to place the points on an outline as shown in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzGW4TDXE-0

Comment: Have you already tried the node `Resample Curve`?

Comment: I know about the Resample curve node, but I don't know how to use it to get the result I want. can you give me some advice?

Comment: I would love to do that if you can give me a curve to work with for that. But unfortunately, from my point of view, your example shown above does not generate the geometry needed for this, because no consistent outline is generated. So I think the real problem lies somewhere else. Therefore, the question should really be *"How can I create an outline around an object?"*

Comment: You are right! So how can I create an outline around the object? I've been searching so far, but haven't been able to find a clear solution. Currently the method that works best is using multiple grids and booleans.

Comment: Well, that's the big question (Which is not easy to answer, by the way). But I would suggest you change that question so that we can get closer to a possible answer. Because once you have created curves that represent an outline of an object, it is only a small step to a correct subdivision and conversion to points.

Comment: I get it! Changed question title. A few days ago I found Line Art Curve Modifier, a paid addon that uses geometry nodes. Lines not dots, but very similar to what I want. https://blendermarket.com/products/line-art-curve-modifer

Comment: I succeeded in creating an outline around the object and resampling it to add dots! However, the curve is a bit unstable, so the position of the vertex flickers. I'll try to find a way to make it more stable. Blend File : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nutIUEuca_n9tiB0d8Tlq4dizP3qhIs9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't know if I'll find the energy to try, so I'll just share an idea: spawn points as you already do, based on normals, but many more points. Then flatten the points to a single plane perpendicular to camera rays. Then you can spawn curves of 0 length on those points and fill the curve. Then delete internal edges (neighbors = 2). Now convert to curve and it's the outline?